# Import friends count from Facebook use IMPORTXML

Tags: facebook, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import the count of friends from my Facebook page into a google spreadsheet. I do this using the IMPORTXML command (Import data from sources in XML, HTML, CSV, TSV format, as well as RSS and ATOM XML.)

`= IMPORTXML (link; query_xpath)`

It seems like I'm doing everything right. Even installed an extension to detect xpath. It determined that I copied the correct path from the code and returned the number of friends. I go to the table with this code, put it in the formula and show me: There is no data to import.

Screenshot - https://gyazo.com/aff19957dddb35ddeddeef9acf0fdec8

Google function - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en

FB page - https://www.facebook.com/rainer.lamish/

What I got

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.facebook.com/linda.lindsey.54379236";"//*[@id='mount_0_0']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/a[3]/div/span/span[2]")
```

But it just gives out `# N / A` instead of the count of friends

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. You have to use the API.

Comment: _“I'm trying to import the count of friends from my Facebook page into a google spreadsheet.”_ - why, what would be the purpose of that? Who needs to do “analytics” on the number of friends they have on facebook?

Comment: Well, there are many ways to make money. And what I wrote about in the question should have made my job a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, [`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) is able to import data saved in XML, HTML, CSV and TSV files. In this case the desired data, friends count, is [obscured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_masking) in the Facebook page, so intentionally there is no data to be imported by `IMPORTXML`. The unexpected response that you got is due to a predictable behaviour by the described interplay between `IMPORTXML` and Facebook. Alternatively, you could try the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) to get the data as @WizKid advised.